# I have developed a Flash Light app. but it does not turn on on high Android version

Tags: java, android

I have developed a Flash Light app. but it does not turn on on high Android version. This app works perfectly on E5 Android 4.4.4 but dont turn on J7 Android 5.1.1 "Lollipop"

Comment: Please include some example code or detailed errors to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Include your android manifest file, how the app fails on on the J7 and the error log please

Comment: Most likely a runtime permissions problems

Answer (score 0):

There can be many issues like till api 19 or 4.4.4 you dont need to ask for permissions or you did not have to worry too much about the device's battery but from the above that version google has fixed some criteria for some functionalities and you need to explicitly ask those permission to user in order to get them working.

So, If you havent already solved it put some code or give some error or log so i can help you more with it.